# Difference between current week of year and previous weeks

Tags: dax

I have a SQL query which calculated the difference between the current weekday and previous weekdays in terms of weeks and I need to translate this to DAX query.

SQL :

```
DATEDIFF(Week,Getdate(),
      DATEADD (WEEK, CAST (RIGHT(CAST ([Code] AS nvarchar),2) AS int),
      DATEADD (YEAR, ([Code] / 100)-1900, 0)) - 4 - 
      DATEPART(dw, 
                 DATEADD (WEEK, CAST (RIGHT(CAST ([Code] AS nvarchar),2) AS int),
       DATEADD (YEAR, ([Code] / 100)-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1)

 AS [WeekIndex]


enter code here
```

Expected Result: If code = 201821 then WeekIndex has to be -53 as the current week is week 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
[Measure] :=
    VAR code = "201821"
    VAR code_year = LEFT ( code, 4 )
    VAR code_week = RIGHT ( code, 2 )
    VAR code_date = DATE ( code_year, 1, -2 ) - WEEKDAY ( DATE ( code_year, 1, 3 ) )
        + code_week * 7
RETURN  
    DATEDIFF ( TODAY (), code_date, WEEK )
```

VAR [code_date] will return the monday of the given VAR [code] as a datevalue

Comment: Hi @Marco , Thank you for replying . I will test it with the actual data :) for now seems to work with test data